# Coredata managedObject issue swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have a table in swift CoreData in that I save records of OrderTable types and fetch saved records from that table to reload the table. with the help of closure, I assign that array value to  an array of  OrderTable type that stores all records and print values in the loop but when I reload a cell from that array it prints nil value when accessing key for that object.

Please help me on that I tried everything. Here're my code and attached a screenshot of problems.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXbrZ.png

```
 ##OrderTable.swift database model file
    ## Save records in database 
            class OrderTable: NSManagedObject {
          // Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass

        class func createInManagedObjectContext(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, dict:[String:AnyObject]) -> OrderTable {
            let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("OrderTable", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as? OrderTable

            newItem?.closedDate = dict["closedDate"]as? String;
            newItem?.modifiedDate = dict["modifiedDate"]as? String
            newItem?.openedDate = dict["openedDate"]as? String
            newItem!.items = dict["items"]as? NSData
            newItem?.server = (dict["server"]as? String?)!
            newItem?.orderNo = dict["orderNo"]as? String
            newItem?.totalPrice = dict["totalPrice"]as? String
            newItem?.tableName = dict["tableName"]as? String
            moc.saveRecursively()
            return newItem!
        }


    ## Get records from database

        class func getOrders(moc:NSManagedObjectContext,postCompleted : (succeeded: Bool, result:[OrderTable]?) -> ()){
            // 9911882342 dilip

           // var arrayRecords = [OrderTable]()

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest();

            moc.performBlockAndWait({
                let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("OrderTable",inManagedObjectContext: moc)

                fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription

                do {
                    let resultOrders = try moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)as? [OrderTable]

                    postCompleted(succeeded:true,result: resultOrders );

                } catch {
                    let fetchError = error as NSError
                    debugPrint(fetchError)
                    postCompleted(succeeded: false, result: nil)
                }


            })


        }
    }

    ##Controller class to get and load table from database values


    //
    //  OrderOpenAndCloseViewController.swift
    //  POSApp
    //


    import Foundation
    import UIKit
    import CoreData
    class OrderOpenAndCloseViewController: UIViewController{

        @IBOutlet weak var tableViewOrderListing: UITableView!

        var arrayExistingOrders = [OrderTable]() // stores existing orders

        let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack() // use for multithreaded coredata

        let viewControllerUtils =   ViewControllerUtils();// use for activity indicator

        //MARK: view Life cycle

       override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }
        override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        }
        override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated);

         // call method to get records from database
            getOpenExistingOrders();
        }

      //MARK: get all open existing orders from database

        func getOpenExistingOrders(){

            viewControllerUtils.showActivityIndicator(self.view)

            if let newPrivateQueueContext =
                self.coreDataStack.newPrivateQueueContext(){ // create new NSmanagedObject context 


                // call getOrder method of OrderTable to get orders from database with the help of closure and assign that to arrayExistingOrders of type OrderTable

                OrderTable.getOrders(newPrivateQueueContext, postCompleted: { (succeeded, result) in

                    self.arrayExistingOrders = result!

                    let item = self.arrayExistingOrders.last // for value check get last object and print orderNo from that

                    print("order no =%@",item?.orderNo)// prints here value or in loop also 1000-001 etc

                    self.tableViewOrderListing.reloadData()

                    self.viewControllerUtils.hideActivityIndicator(self.view) // hide loader
                })

            }
        }
      }
      //MARK: tableview datasource methods
    extension OrderOpenAndCloseViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return arrayExistingOrders.count // return number of orders
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OrderOpenAndCloseCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as? OrderOpenAndCloseCell

            let item = arrayExistingOrders[indexPath.item]
            print("orderNo =%@",item.orderNo) //here prints orderNo =%@ nil instead of value order no =%@ Optional("1000-001") etc


            let orderNo = item.orderNo

            var totalOrderCost:String?

            if let totalcost  = item.totalPrice{
                totalOrderCost = totalcost

            }else{
                totalOrderCost = ""
            }

            let serverName = item.server

            let openedDate = item.openedDate

            cell?.labelOrderNo.text = orderNo;

            cell?.labelServerName.text = serverName;

            cell?.labelOpenedDate.text = openedDate

            cell?.labelTotalPrice.text = totalOrderCost

            return cell!;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this line:

```
if let newPrivateQueueContext =
    self.coreDataStack.newPrivateQueueContext
```

You then use `newPrivateQueueContext` to perform the fetch. Then you let `newPrivateContext` go out of scope, which causes it to be deallocated.

When you fetch a managed object, that managed object **needs** its managed object context, but it does not keep a strong reference to it. If the managed object context is deallocated, any managed objects that have been fetched from it are now useless. You can print results **while the context still exists** but as soon as you let it be deallocated you can't use the results any more.

You need to keep a strong reference to the context that you use for fetching, for as long as you need to use the results of the fetch. That probably means making it a property of your view controller, but there are many ways to do that.

Comment: Thanks Tom, It help me to fix that issue.